# Blender Eevee lighting Rendering - Flashes of light in animation

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I am experiencing a strange lighting effect with my last 2 rendered video animations in Blender.

The only thing I think my last to video animations had in common is the presence of more than one source of light in the fixed camera scene.

At random times during the animation strong and 1 frame long flashed of light appear.  They have the colour of one of the lights present in the animation in the screenshot below you can see one of these flashes.

[image]

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and if I can eliminate all the flashes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try lowering the bloom threshold

Comment: currently, the bloom threshold is 8  should I bring it down to 3 or 2 or go up to 100 because it seems the more I go up the less the light effect?

Comment: Maybe you have accidentally keyed the light intensity.

Comment: do you mean I keyframed in the lights during the rotation animation?  I checked for keyframes in the lights timeline but there were not.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? In alpha stage of Blender 2.80, this happen a lot in my experience when volumetric are enabled in my scene. At that time, I manually replace the corrupt image with the re-rendered one. Which is not a good solution

Comment: I am using blender 2.81 and waiting to upgrade directly to 2.9 when it comes out. I am considering rendering all the frames to images and as you said then replace the defective ones manually to finally use the compositor.

Comment: Does it happen at the same frame when you render it again? BTW Your file would be welcomed, just delete all parts of the scene that doesn't generate the issue. Thanks

Comment: No every time I try to render it the flashes occur at a different timing. I am in fact rendering the rotation frame by frame right now.  When done I will substitute the defective frames.

Comment: When I said file, I meant to share simplifies blend file with issue via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into what may be the same issue rendering out some of my scenes with eevvee.  See screen shot.  I did a bit of investigation and where I have a stack of point lights in a complicated mesh every now and then I'll get that flash.  If I turned off bloom it stopped, looking at the rendered image it would have a few super white pixels for some reason that bloom was really blooming on causing the flashes.
I added a clamp value to the bloom (20 in my case worked) and it stops that happening.
To re-render the affected scenes without redoing the whole thing I tweaked my command line batch render as below just to re-render the affected frames.

"--path to your blender install--\blender.exe" -b  "P.Scene4.Cut1.blend" -f 2,5,36,51,52,53,70,75,77,78,104,105,114,119,137,149,169,174,186,221,232,233,241,246,247,250,252,259,266,276,277,280,283

Perhaps you issue is different but check bloom clamp, 0 is the default and that means no clamp at all.[image]

Comment: I am rendering with 20 clamp right now.

Comment: Cool let me know how it goes! FYI on some of my other scenes where I Also had issues and I had a lot of bloom going on I upped the clamp setting to 200 (this actually allows more bloom) and it still worked to stop the flashing so if you find 20 reduces the overall bloom too much for your taste but did resolve the issue try something around 200. Good luck!

Comment: Tried at 30 and the flashes were reduced a lot.  I will try at higher and see how it goes.

Comment: The render went quite well but not perfect.  At 30 clamp bloom flares were much reduced but still present.  At 200 clamp again bloom flares were much reduced but still present. However, I did as I was once suggested and corrected the defective frame in the sequencer and rendered the animation again perfect this time.